# necesito ejecutar locationmanager en la api 23 (Marshmallow) me aparece un error de permisos ya los tengo agregados en el manifest.xml

Tags: android

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MyLocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocListener.setMainActivity(this);

    **mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) mlocListener);**


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: tu disposito es Android 6.0 ? la forma de requerir permisos es diferente.

Comment: si, el dispositivo donde necesito ejecutar la aplicacion cuenta con la version 6.0

Comment: ok estoy agregando mi respuesta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los permisos definidos en el Manifest.xml para usar geolocalización son:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

#### Si tu dispositivo es Android 6.0 debes requerir los permisos de esta forma:

Antes de llamar el método `requestLocationUpdates()` debes realizar la comprobación de permisos de esta forma (en este ejemplo tu Actividad debe extender de AppCompatActivity:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Requiere permisos para Android 6.0
    Log.e("Location", "No se tienen permisos necesarios!, se requieren.");
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 225);
    return;
}else{
    Log.i("Location", "Permisos necesarios OK!.");
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) mlocListener);
}
```

Comment: Excelente aportacion, personas como usted valen demasiado por compartir sus conocimientos.......

Comment: Excelente aporte! me has ayudado mucho!